# AWS Neptune Gremlin .Net: Update a Vertex property after finding the vertex by the same property

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have added a vertex using this C# code.

```
g.addV("LabelX").Property("uid", "1").Property("name", "x").Property("description", "desc").Next();
```

Now, I want to update the value of 'name' property to "x1" of the same vertex based on two query parameters.
Parameter1: uid = 1
Parameter2: name = x

How can I write the C# gremlin query to perform this update so that if two calls goes to to server with same request then only 1 is committed and other one returns an error?

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you are creating the vertex if it does not exist, and then changing an additional property once created or found, you would typically use the `fold` ... `coalesce` pattern. Once Neptune adds support for Apache TinkerPop 3.6.x, using the new `mergeV` step is also an option.

However, in this particular case, where you just want to set a property, rather than try to get one query to succeed and the other to fail, it's probably easier to just ensure that the query uses `Single` cardinality. That way, even if they both succeed, the value will be the same. Neptune will prevent two queries from updating the same property at the exact same time, but will also do automatic retries if a property is initially found to be locked by another query. You will only get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if Neptune is unable to automatically resolve the conflict. So it's probably best to just assume they can both succeed and make sure to use a Single cardinality update.

Something like:

```java
g.V().Has("LabelX","uid", "1").
      Has("name", "x").
      Property(Cardinality.Single, "name", "x1").
      Next()
```